# Trying to add Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 to ConEmu

Tags: visual-studio-2015, conemu

I am trying to add the Developer Command Prompt For VS2015 to my ConEmu tasks so that I can start a shell from there. I know that I have to add a task under startup in the Settings, but I have no idea where to start or what to do.

I know that the command prompt shortcut is here:

```
..\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2015\Visual Studio Tools
```

and the shortcut points to:

```
..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat
```

Answer (score 6):

You will need to create a new predefined task under the Startup-->Tasks menu in the ConEmu settings.

Click on the '+' button and call it whatever you like, in the screenshot below I called it VSCommandLine.

You will need to add the following commands in the command window:

```
* > cmd.exe /k ""%VS140COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat" & powershell" -new_console:d:C:\SourceCode\MyStartupDirectory
```

[image: Screenshot of ConEmu Startup-->Tasks Settings Menu]

Comment: @Maximus where?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu What?

Comment: @Maximus oh, The SDK::VS 14.0, i've seen it... thanks.